# Swift Difference between ampersand and comma when conforming to protocols

Tags: swift

I was reading documentation about Swift Protocol Composition and found this:
[https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#:~:text=Reference%20Types.-,Protocol%20Composition,-It%20can%20be](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#:%7E:text=Reference%20Types.-,Protocol%20Composition,-It%20can%20be)

> It can be useful to require a type to conform to multiple protocols at
> the same time. You can combine multiple protocols into a single
> requirement with a protocol composition. Protocol compositions behave
> as if you defined a temporary local protocol that has the combined
> requirements of all protocols in the composition. Protocol
> compositions don’t define any new protocol types.
>
> Protocol compositions have the form SomeProtocol & AnotherProtocol.
> You can list as many protocols as you need, separating them with
> ampersands (&). In addition to its list of protocols, a protocol
> composition can also contain one class type, which you can use to
> specify a required superclass.
>
> Here’s an example that combines two protocols called Named and Aged
> into a single protocol composition requirement on a function
> parameter:

```
protocol Named {
    var name: String { get }
}
protocol Aged {
    var age: Int { get }
}
struct Person: Named, Aged {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}
func wishHappyBirthday(to celebrator: Named & Aged) {
    print("Happy birthday, \(celebrator.name), you're \(celebrator.age)!")
}
let birthdayPerson = Person(name: "Malcolm", age: 21)
wishHappyBirthday(to: birthdayPerson)
// Prints "Happy birthday, Malcolm, you're 21!"
```

Could someone maybe explain the difference between the ampersand and the comma when stating that a type conforms to two or more protocols? I tested this in Playgrounds and both the ampersand and comma worked just fine. I tried doing some research online but didn't really find a good answer for this..

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/differences-between-type-inheritance-clause-protocol-composition-syntax/47940

Answer (score 4):

You use the `,` in type declarations, like your `struct Person: Named, Aged`.

But for argument lists and other contexts, the `,` already is a separator. So to specify a type that means "must conform both to protocol Foo and protocol Bar" a different character is necessary. That's why you need to write `func wishHappyBirthday(to celebrator: Named & Aged)`. The same is true for writing variables, like `let anotherCelebrator: Named & Aged = …`. You can also do type aliases like this: `typealias NamedAndAged = Named & Aged`.

So the question is, why don't we use the `&` when declaring a type? I *think* the answer is history, as far I remember protocol composition wasn't available in Swift 1 (couldn't find when it was introduced; Swift 4?). And it turn out you *can* use `&` instead in a lot of cases:

```
struct Foo: Codable & Identifiable {
    var id: UUID { UUID() }
}
        
class Bar: NSObject & Codable {
}
```

It does not work with the first and second type of an `enum`: `enum Baz: Int & CaseIterable { … }` yields a compiler error, but `enum Baz: Int, CaseIterable & Identifiable { … }` is allowed.

Comment: I think there is some case when `&` cannot be used in inheritance clause but I cannot find it right now.

Comment: @Sulthan: There are probably several more cases (like `enum`, as I just found out) where it doesn't work. Maybe the Swift team fixes some of these someday, but there's not much need to do so, I guess.